# Using an oscillator instead of a crystal on W5500

Tags: oscillator, crystal

I am designing a circuit I am planning to have fabricated that uses the W5500 Ethernet IC. I am quite new when with this and I've heard of a number of people having problems with the crystal (bad tuning, no start, etc.) that goes with the W5500.

I need to get this circuit working on the first try (not enough time to iterate) so I was wondering if I could use an oscillator in it's place to avoid potential problems. My understanding is that they are pretty much guaranteed to work albeit at a higher cost.

[image]

How would an oscillator be connected to the W5500? Should I just connect the oscillator output to CLKIN? Does the oscillator replace the crystal and capacitors or also the 1M resistor (R14)?

These are the W5500 crystal requirements:

[image]

Would [this oscillator](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810170926_SJK-SHENZHEN-CRYSTAL-TECH-2N25000G33YC_C252327.pdf) be good for the W5500? Is its output compatible with the levels expected by W5500's CLKIN?

---

I am an idiot, just got the answer for the first question from the W5500 datasheet:

[image]

The oscillator I referenced seems to have a CMOS output instead of TTL output so I suppose it won't work.

Can I use a CMOS oscillator with a device that expects TTL clock in?

EDIT: Would [this TTL/CMOS compatible oscillator](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2106070533_JYJE-TO2125000CWBC_C2681255.pdf) work with the W5500?

Comment: tomas1808 - Hi, You added an "answer" which self-answered the original question, but then it asked a new question. Stack Exchange rules mean that questions need to be asked in the question section at the top of the screen, not in the answer section at the bottom of the screen. Therefore your "answer" has been moved into the question, as an edit. However you have also now changed the question (generally that's not a good plan here, but since you had no answers, it didn't invalidate existing answers). Please [edit] your question if you need to clarify further. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CMOS/TTL part you showed is expected to work, as long as you run it on 3.3V Vcc.